# I want to compare two columns and copy cells

Tags: excel, vba

I want to compare two columns and copy the 4 cells found next to the comparing value found in column 1, this row should than be copied into column 2 in the first empty row.

```
Sub Find_Matches()

    Dim CompareRange1 As Variant, CompareRange2 As Variant, x As Variant, y As Variant
    ' Set CompareRange equal to the range to which you will
    ' compare the selection.
    Set CompareRange1 = Range("A1:A10")
    Set CompareRange2 = Range("H1:H30") 
    For Each x In CompareRange1
        For Each y In CompareRange2
            Dim a As Variant
            Set a = x.Offset(0,4)
            If x = y Then y.Offset(1, 4) = a
        Next y
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Why all the tags? access-vba, word-vba,outlook-vba and excel-vba all are slightly different.

Comment: You also need to tell us what error you are getting and where.  I do not see anywhere where you try to do what you want outside of looping through the two ranges.  I do not see where you try to copy 4 cells and paste then in the next available row.

Comment: Is this better? Sorry this is my first time asking a question. I am unsure which formula to use but I cant set a = x.Offset (0,4).Select

Comment: Is `Set CompareRange2 = Range("H1:H30") For Each x In CompareRange1` On the same line? The For needs to be on a new line

Comment: Remove the `.Select` from that line.  when setting you do not select.

Comment: So now what is your problem?  The code runs fine.

Comment: Why use `a` at all? Why not simply use `If x = y Then y.Offset(1, 4) =x.Offset(0,4)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you're after:

```
Sub Find_Matches()
    Dim CompareRange1 As Variant, CompareRange2 As Variant, x As Variant, y As Variant
    Set CompareRange1 = Range("A1:A10")
    Set CompareRange2 = Range("H1:H30")
    For Each x In CompareRange1
        For Each y In CompareRange2
            If x = y Then y.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 4).Value = x.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 4).Value
        Next y
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: It alsmost works, but now it only copies one match A-A, and I want it to copy every match A-A. Can you help me out?

Comment: Code above will compare [A1 with H1], then [A1 with H2], [A1 with H3]..all the way to.. [A1 with H30], then  [A2 with H1], then [A2 with H2] and on and on and where a match exists, it copies the four cells to the right of the [A] cell match to the four cells to the right of the [H]. Is that not what you wanted?

Comment: yes it is but it only copying 1 match in stead of all the matches.

Comment: Hi Laurie, there's nothing in the code that would prevent it from copying more than one instance of a match. Is it possible it's copying blank cells so  as to appear as though it's not doing anything at all?

Comment: no its looks like its copying the new values over eachother so only 1 match becomes visable.

Comment: so it also needs to find the next empty cell